# C# Custom Action goes in error. Anyone got idea of this error?

Tags: c#, oracle, windows-installer, advanced-installer

In this CustomAction there is a connection to an Oracle Database, simple.
I got to retreive the names from a table. The problem is it cannot connect. The fact is in the Installation Sequence i got another Custom Action that does a connection and it works.

Here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;


namespace CustomAction1
{
   public class CustomActions
   {
     [CustomAction]
     public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
      {
        string ConnectionString = "User Id=NO;Password=NO;Data Source=NO";
        string properties;
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
        {

            con.Open();
            using (OracleCommand retreive = new OracleCommand("select TABLE_EL from TABLE", con))
            using (OracleDataReader rd = retreive.ExecuteReader())
            {
                properties = null;
                int i = 0;
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    if (properties != null)
                        properties = properties + "," + rd.GetString(0).Trim();
                    else
                        properties = rd.GetString(0).Trim();
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        session["ELENCODITTE"] = properties;
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Here's the exception thrown

```
Exception thrown by custom action:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.RegAndConfigRdr' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section startup. (C:\Users\davanzo\AppData\Local\Temp\6\MSI9D8D.tmp-\CustomAction.config line 3)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.RegAndConfigRdr..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.RegAndConfigRdr.ReadEntriesForRegistryAndConfig()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at CustomAction1.CustomActions.CustomAction1(Session session) in C:\Users\davanzo\source\repos\FetchDitte\FetchDitte\CustomAction.cs:line 20
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object parameters, Object arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32 sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr)
CustomAction FetchDitte.CA.dll_1 returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 15:31:25: FetchDitte.CA.dll_1. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (4C:28) [15:31:25:353]: Doing action: FatalError
Action 15:31:25: FatalError. 
Action start 15:31:25: FatalError.
```

Comment: This seems to be the source of the problem: _"System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section startup. (C:\Users\davanzo\AppData\Local\Temp\6\MSI9D8D.tmp-\CustomAction.config line 3)"_ - what's in the `CustomAction.config` file?

Comment: '<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by installing nuget package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

Answer (score 0):

the explication is in the error itself:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section startup.
I think you forgot to add the proper setting in configSections of your config file, that tells the framework how to handle the configuration of a custom section.

Comment: I got another Custom Action with the exactly same configuration file and that works.

Comment: I think the problem is in the app.config of your application, not the CustomAction.config file.

Comment: Initially there wasn't an App.config file, I copy-pasted form the other CustomAction, but seems it didn't recognized or something. How can I attach that configuration file to the project?

Comment: Make sure the App.config file is copied to the output folder. You can check the properties of the file in Solution Explorer.

Comment: Found the solution, I had to install Oracle.ManagedDataAccess nuget package.